Why can we use $|p| \approx\hbar /\langle x\rangle$ as an approximation?
In our lecture, the approximation for the zeeman energy shift is
$$\frac{2e \vec{p} \vec{A}}{2m} \approx \frac{e \hbar B}{m}.$$
Here, symmetric gauge was used (therefore $A \approx r B$) and my question is about $|p| \approx\hbar /\langle x\rangle$.
The uncertainty is of course clear and $\Delta x \propto \hbar / \Delta p$ but there is two steps, which are quite common, that I do not understand well theoretically: firstly why can we replace the variance $\Delta$ with the absolute values. Secondly there could be a huge factor, the relation just states $\hbar \leq \Delta x\Delta p$ but this makes again no statement about absolute values.

Using $\vert p\vert$ (without average values) $\approx \hbar/\langle x\rangle$ is very dangerous.  Take the combination $(\vert 0\rangle +\vert 2\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$ and evolve it in time: $\langle x\rangle=0$ but $\langle p\rangle\ne 0$.  Moreover, you can imagine a displaced harmonic oscillator so that $\langle x\rangle$ is as large as you want without affecting $\vert p\vert$.  This approximation must be specific to this problem and the notation is probably very loose.

I think this should be taken in the spirit of dimensional analysis.
